# Tomcat 8: Unable to overcome common error: The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly

Tags: apache, tomcat

I know that this is not the first time that this error has been addressed, but after looking at many posts, I'm not sure where I am going wrong. I am trying to start up a Tomcat 8 that I downloaded. I have zero experience in the Java world. Right now I am missing Microsoft MSI setup wizards :-)

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\C39293>echo %classpath%
c:\Informatica\9.1.0\DataTransformation\api\lib\CM_JavaAPI.jar; ;.;C:\PROGRA~2\S
QLLIB\java\db2java.zip;C:\PROGRA~2\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc.jar;C:\PROGRA~2\SQLLIB\jav
a\sqlj.zip;C:\PROGRA~2\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc_license_cu.jar;C:\PROGRA~2\SQLLIB\bin;
C:\PROGRA~2\SQLLIB\java\common.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\SQLLIB\java\db2java.zip;C:\PROGRA
~1\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\SQLLIB\java\sqlj.zip;C:\PROGRA~1\SQLLIB\ja
va\db2jcc_license_cu.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\SQLLIB\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\SQLLIB\java\common.j
ar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin

C:\Users\C39293>echo %CATALINA_HOME%
C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.17\bin

C:\Users\C39293>echo %JRE_HOME%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\

C:\Users\C39293>cd C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.17

C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.17>cd bin

C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.17\bin>catalina
The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
```

**Any idea which environment variables look wrong?** Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CATALINA_HOME must be set to '*C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.17*' in your case. 'bin' directory is also included so it could be the reason that you see error.

Comment: Thank you. That worked, I believe. When I executed catalina start from the bin folder I saw the following out put but I got "Page Cannot Be Displayed" when I tried to acecss localhost:8080. The output from the catalina start was as follows. Any idea? C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.17
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.17"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.17"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.17\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.17\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\apache-tomc
at-8.0.17\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"

Comment: If CATALINA_BASE is not defined it uses the same as CATALINA_HOME. Are you still facing any issue?

Comment: Well, the catalina batch file *looked* like it progressed beyond the error I mentioned in my post, but I am unable to access the web site usinbg the expected URL: http://localhost:8080. So, yes, I am still facing issues. In a Pluralsight training video, they showed that that url should bring up a sample page. The cmd window brought up another window, but it quickly went away, so I guess it failed somewhere./ There is no log file. Maybe I have to start writing echos in the batch file, yuck.

Comment: Well, you may check %CATALINA_HOME%\logs\catalina.out file for the stacktrace.

Comment: There was no log file produced in that location

Comment: Would you like to start tomcat from command prompt? say go to %CATALINA_HOME%\bin then run startup.bat script and see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69033/discussion-between-chadd-and-rao).